# Print multiple files as one print job using FinePrint

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I want to print all selected files which are displayed in a Datagrid.

I don´t want to print them one after another, I want all to add them into a print queue because I want to use [FinePrint](http://fineprint.com/fp/).

FinePrint is a printer driver that can add all documents in the print queue to a single file for printing. In Windows Explorer you can select files and right-click `Print` on them. When FinePrint is selected as the default printer it opens the FinePrint Window and attaches all the selected Files to one file. Then you can do other stuff like set stamps on the pages.

I want to create the same thing in my WPF project, but it would be enough to just select files and click on a button.

**EDIT:**

The complete Method:

```
void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<ZeichnungInDB> selectedItemsList = dataOutOfDb.SelectedItems.Cast<ZeichnungInDB>().ToList();
    if(selectedItemsList.Count > 0)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        FileInfo fileInfo;
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach (ZeichnungInDB zeichnung in selectedItemsList)
            {
                fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"..." + zeichnung.Zeichnungsnummer + "_" + zeichnung.Index + "_VIN_" + zeichnung.Volante_Index + zeichnung.Extension);
                using (FileStream file = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                {
                    System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext context = new System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext();
                    context.BaseUri = new Uri(fileInfo.FullName, UriKind.Absolute);
                    object doc = (System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(file, context));
                    DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator;
                    printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Printing from MMS");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws a `XamlParseException` where I create the doc object, directly at the beginning of the File.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you set a registry key (counter) and then print them the normal way (one after another) FinePrint decrements the counter and adds them to one job.

From: http://fineprint.com/fpsupport-topic/fineprint-developer-kit/

> Using the CollectJobs registry setting, FinePrint will collect
>   multiple print jobs before printing them.
>
> The DWORD registry key is:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/FinePrint
>   Software/FinePrint8/FinePrinters/FinePrint/CollectJobs
>
> Set the CollectJobs value to the number of print jobs you want to
>   combine. Each time FinePrint receives a print job, it decrements the
>   counter. The counter value should be checked to ensure that it has
>   been decremented before the next job is sent. When all the jobs have
>   been collected and sent to the output device, the counter is set to
>   zero.

Comment: How you mean that? I have no Idea. I found tons of examples for print print PDF´s but I don´t want to print only this. I want to print just all files I want.

Comment: This might be me but your comment makes no sense to me. I interpreted your question as "how do I add multiple files to one print job" which I tried answering. Elaborate your question with some example code and explain what the problem is.

Comment: I don´t know how to create a registry key with that. And I just want to show the PrintDialog and then just use the PrintDocument Method to print every File I selected in the DataGrid. But thereror I need a DocumentPaginator and I have no Idea to create it, because I have many different Extensions and can´t just built one.

Comment: "I don´t know how to create a registry key with that." This is a different question altogether but [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/h5e7chcf.aspx). About your DocumentPaginator, this was already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396213/printing-dynamic-usercontrol-via-document-paginator-in-wpf-datagrid-is-printed
It was explicitly created for the printing of a DataGrid.

Comment: Hm actually I have FileInfo-Objects or can create them easy because I have the Path´s of the Files. Can I use the FileInfo to create the Paginator? I googled for a while now but didn´t found something interesting. This would be the best solution, if I use it like this.

Comment: You can, but why re-invent the wheel? a small example how you could accomplish this:
`FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
using (FileStream file = fileInfo.OpenRead())
{
System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext context = new System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext();
context.BaseUri = new Uri(fileInfo.FullName, UriKind.Absolute);
doc = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(file, context);
}`
To me this seems like the long way around.

Comment: Yes that might be true, but as long as it works how I want it to work and I understand it, it´s the best solution. Hm, I think one last question remaining. What type is "doc"?

Comment: object, you should be able to cast it to IDocumentPaginatorSource. use it like this: `DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator;`

Comment: IDocumentPaginatorSource doc = (IDocumentPaginatorSource) (System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(file, context));
Hm, at this Line it throws XamlParsException. I tried i out with DocumentPaginator and FixedDocument, too.
I trhows the exception at the start of the Load();  First Line and first Position.
And your new solution.